# Losing ACTION_DOWN parameters when InterceptTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch-event, intercept

I have a parent view which should follow finger on touch and a child view inside it which is clickable. So I used **onInterceptTouchEvent** to decide if I have to consume the touch event on parent or child by comparing the touch distance before ACTION_UP.

obviously I used "retrun false" on ACTION_DOWN in onInterceptTouchEvent (because it is too early to propagate the event before calculations) So unfortunately the onTouch loses the ACTION_DOWN.

The question is how can I initialize parameters (as well as initial position of parent view) from **onTouch** (not from onInterceptTouchEvent)?

Footnote: For a reason I have to write **onTouch** inline with other codes where I have implemented onInterceptTouchEvent inside the object definition.

a part of Object Definition:

```
boolean mmIsBeingDragged; 
float mLastX;
float mStartX;
int mTouchSlop=ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mLastX = event.getX();
            mStartX = mLastX;
           break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            float xDelta = Math.abs(x - mLastX);

            float xDeltaTotal = x - mStartX;
            if (Math.abs(xDeltaTotal) > mTouchSlop) {
                mmIsBeingDragged = true;
                mStartX = x;
                return true;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mmIsBeingDragged = false;
            break;
    }
     return false;
}
```

and this is ontouch which is defined outside of object (inline with program)

```
    myview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        float curX=0;
        float oldX;
        float startX;
        float delta=0;
        float togo;
        boolean mIsBeingDragged=false;
        int mTouchSlop=ViewConfiguration.get(getActivity()).getScaledTouchSlop();

        @Override 
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //Here is the prblem! How to initialize startX?

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                curX = event.getRawX();
                delta=curX-startX;
                togo=oldX+delta;

                if (Math.abs(delta) > mTouchSlop) {
                    mIsBeingDragged=true;
                    followfingerFunction(v,togo)
                    return true;
                }
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!mIsBeingDragged){v.performClick();}
                break;
        }
            return true;
    }
    });
```

Comment: So the child view has OnTouchListener set and the parent View has a custom implementation of onInterceptTouchEvent ?

Comment: No. Both of these definition is on the parent object. onInterceptTouchEvent is defined in the parent object definition and OnTouchListener is added to the parent object inline with other codes after inflating.

Comment: I have provided my answer. Pls check. It is quite simple, but i think it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expose your mStartX to your activity. ( I know it not perfect but seems OK).

```
class ParentView extends ViewGroup (or some other viewGroup) {
    int startX;
    public int getStartX(){
        return startX;
    }
}
```

// After that just call getStartX() from your activity.